# How to record the time spent exchanging data between functions in Durable functions

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-durable-functions

I am planning to use Azure's Durable functions to measure the time it takes to transfer data.

Specifically, I want to send data from an activity function to an orchestration function and record the time it takes to receive the data.

The following functions will not work, but what you want to do is,

1. create data of the type and size specified by the activity function
2. record the time before transfer
3. transfer the data to the orchestration function
4. orchestration function receives the value and records the time
5. calculate the time taken to transfer the data
   I am happy if you can understand what I want to do.

How can I modify the following code to measure the time from the start of sending data to the completion of receiving data?

> ```
> import azure.functions as func
> import azure.durable_functions as df
> import logging
> import numpy as np
> import pandas as pd
> import pickle
> import random
> import time
>
> # This is not a very relevant function.
> app = df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
> @app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
> @app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
> async def client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse:
>
>     # Start of orchestration
>     instance_id = await client.start_new("orchestrator", None, {})
>     logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")
>     
>     # Wait for orchestration to complete
>     await client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
>
>     # Get orchestration execution status
>     status = await client.get_status(instance_id)
>
>     # Get the result of orchestration execution
>     runtime = status.runtime_status
>     output = status.output
>     return f"runtime: {runtime}\n\noutput:{output}" 
>
>
>
> @app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
> def orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
>     result = context.call_activity("activity1", "")
>     transfer_time = time.time() - start
>     return transfer_time
>
>
> @app.activity_trigger(input_name="blank")
> def activity1(blank: str) -> str:
>     data = np.random.rand(1024*1024)  # Generate random data
>     df = pd.DataFrame(data)  # Create a DataFrame
>     df_pickle = pickle.dumps(df)  # Serialization
>     start = time.time()
>     return df_pickle
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I am able to get the time which is been taken by the activity function with the help of below code*

```
import  azure.functions  as  func
import  azure.durable_functions  as  df
import  logging
import  numpy  as  np
import  pandas  as  pd
import  pickle
import  random
import  time
  

# This is not a very relevant function.
app  =  df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
@app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
@app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async  def  client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse: 

# Start of orchestration
instance_id  =  await  client.start_new("orchestrator", None, {})

logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")

# Wait for orchestration to complete
await  client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
# Get orchestration execution status
status  =  await  client.get_status(instance_id)
# Get the result of orchestration execution
runtime  =  status.runtime_status
output  =  status.output
return  f"runtime: {runtime}\n\noutput:{output}" 

@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def  orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
start  =  time.time()
result  =  yield  context.call_activity("activity1", "")
transfer_time  =  time.time() -  start
return  transfer_time

@app.activity_trigger(input_name="blank")
def  activity1(blank: str) -> str:
data  =  np.random.rand(700*700)
# Generate random data
df  =  pd.DataFrame(data) # Create a DataFrame
df_  =  df.to_dict()
#df_pickle = pickle.dumps(df_) # Serialization
return  df_
```

**Please Note** `df_pickle = pickle.dumps(df_)` will not work here as durable function needs output in JSON serializable format but pickle, serializing it in byte format. So, you need to use `df.to_dict()` instead.

You need to capture the start time before calling the activity function in orchestrator function and calculate `transfer_time`  after getting the result from activity function.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: You changed only the orchestration and activity functions in my source code, right?<br\>
I would replace the original orchestration and activity functions with the code you suggested,
**runtime: OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.**
**output:None**
and the time may not be output. What is the cause?

Comment: What's the value you are giving here `np.random.rand(700*700)`?

Comment: I am planning to transfer data of a specified size, such as 1KB or 1MB.
In order to create data of a specified size, I can change the number.

Comment: I believe you can pass the values `np.random.rand(700*700)` or till `np.random.rand(800*800)` due to memory limitation. If you give more value then runtime: OrchestrationRuntimeStatus will keep showing you pending and every time output will be None due to consumption.

Comment: I have tried with 1024*1024 but it is consuming more memory, so my function is getting stopped at `runtime: OrchestrationRuntimeStatus:pending` state

Comment: So for the free Azure quota, does that mean that the maximum number of exchanges between activity functions is 700*700?
Is there any way to send a size larger than this?

Comment: You need to check the maximum exchanges by providing various combinations. Premium function app plan can give me some extra memory. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62187442/is-the-1-5-gb-memory-limit-in-azure-functions-limited-to-the-entire-function-app

Comment: @TY00 is function working as expected for you for lower combination values?

Comment: I see that for a free frame, you can't transfer a larger value, and that 700*700 is not even 1MB, so you can only send a very small amount.
I can confirm that it works correctly in my environment for 700*700 or less!