# How to measure communication time between instances with Durable functions?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

In Azure's Durable functions, I would like to investigate the impact on response time when the number of instances increases.

I want to measure the response time when activity functions are connected in a sequential process of function chain and executed in the order of Activity function 1 -> Activity function 2 -> .... We want to measure the response time when they are executed in the order of Activity function 1 -> Activity function 2 -> ....

The following is a sample code.
Please modify the sample code so that we can measure the impact of the number of activity functions on the response time.

```
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df
import logging
import time

## Client functions are not considered relevant this time.
app = df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
@app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
@app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse:

    instance_id = await client.start_new("orchestrator", None, {})
    logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")
    
    await client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)

    status = await client.get_status(instance_id)

    runtime = status.runtime_status
    output = status.output
    return f"runtime: {runtime}\n\noutput:{output}" 


## Overall response time when multiple activity functions are invoked in a function chain
@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext) -> float:
    start = time.time()
    a = context.call_activity("activity1", "")
    b = context.call_activity("activity2", "")
    return_time = time.time() - start
    return return_time


## Sample Activity Functions
@app.activity_trigger(input_name="blank")
def activity1(blank: str) :
    time.sleep(10)
    return None

@app.activity_trigger(input_name="blank")
def activity2(blank: str):
    time.sleep(10)
    return None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get the time taken by each activity function with the help of below code.
for reference I have used this code form this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77227043/how-to-record-the-time-spent-exchanging-data-between-functions-in-durable-functi). To perform some execution inside the activity function.

I made some changes in `Orchestration function` to get the required output.

I tried using `time.sleep(10)` but 10 seconds is throwing status as `Pending` and output as `None`.

for me `time.sleep()` lowest second is working is 1 second and it is throwing value as `0.0`.

[image]

I have used `yield` method while calling activity function. through which it will wait for value to be returned before executing new line.

**My code:**

**`function_app.py`:**

```py
import  azure.functions  as  func
import  azure.durable_functions  as  df
import  logging
import  numpy  as  np
import  pandas  as  pd
import  pickle
import  random
import  time
  
app  =  df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
@app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
@app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async  def  client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse: 

    instance_id  =  await  client.start_new("orchestrator", None, {})

    logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")

    await  client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)

    status  =  await  client.get_status(instance_id)

    runtime  =  status.runtime_status
    output  =  status.output
    return  f"runtime: {runtime}\n\noutput:{output}" 

@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def  orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
    start  =  time.time()
    a =  yield context.call_activity("activity1", "")
    time1 = float(time.time()-start)
    b =  yield context.call_activity("activity2", "")
    time2= float(time.time()-(start+time1))
    total_time= float(time.time()-start)
    
    return  {
        "total time": total_time,
        "time taken for activity1": time1,
        "time taken for activity2": time2,
    }

@app.activity_trigger(input_name="blank")
def  activity1(blank: str) -> str:
    data = np.random.rand(500*500)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df_ = df.to_dict()
    return df_

@app.activity_trigger(input_name="blank")
def  activity2(blank: str) -> str:
    data = np.random.rand(500*500)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df_ = df.to_dict()
    return df_
```

**`Output`:**

[image]

Comment: Does creating an appropriate data frame instead of a sleep function in the activity function make a significant difference in provisioning time?
Also, does the data size change significantly by using to_dict instead of pickle?

Comment: **Does creating an appropriate data frame instead of a sleep function in the activity function make a significant difference in provisioning time?**
yes,

**does the data size change significantly by using `to_dict` instead of `pickle`?** 
yes, because `pickle` is used for general purpose serialization where as `to_dict` is used to serialize in compact form. which helps in the  change the size significantly.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have found that to_dict() results in smaller data sizes than pickle.
Does creating a DataFrame function instead of sleep in the activity function make a big difference in the instance startup time?

Comment: @TY00 Yes, I used data frame function to perform some execution inside the activity function so that I can get some actual value in the Output. whereas when using sleep function value was coming as 0 as no execution was being performed and the activity function was idle. which was resulting output either none and status pending on higher value. or 0 in lower value.

Comment: I made one activity function, 500*500 DataFrame to_dict() and return.
Then, "OrchestrationRuntimeStatus" becomes "Pending", "Runnning", or "Completed". Basically, it does not become "Completed".

Why the variation? How can I get it to be "Compleated" consistently?

Comment: @TY00 It depends on device. Try lowering the value. I would suggest to start from 100*100 and increase accordingly. for me 500*500 was the highest in both activity for `completed` consistently.

Comment: They are always very helpful. I may post similar questions in the future. I would be happy to help you then as well.

Comment: @TY00 I am glad It helped you. :)